# how to reserve an empty space for the positive sign

Tags: c++, cout

The flag `std::ios::showpos` prints out the positive sign of a numerical value. What I would like to carry out is to reserve space rather that the positive sign. Is there any flag regarding this matter? I can code a simple if-statement for this issue, however, I'm seeking more elegant way. Boost library is welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::showpos);
    std::cout << 42 << "\n" << -42 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @laser_wizard, yes. Also, I'm storing data into txt file.

Comment: what about your own manipulator?

Comment: @GilsonPJ, I prefer if-statement over implementing a whole class regarding this problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `std::noshowpos` with `std::setw` .

```
std::cout << std::noshowpos<<std::setw(3)<< 42 << "\n" << -42 << std::endl;
```